# Efficiently fueling a generator

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Do i waste coal if i fill up a generator with a full stack of coal to charge my batbox connected to it? I have the feeling it starts to waste coal when the generator gets fully charged and continues to burn coal. Are there any ways to let all the machines run for a while so i do not have to stay in place to fill stuff with fuel?

Currently i am just using coal, but i am building a coke oven so soon i have much better fuel. Do these other fuel types burn slower and give the same power/second or do they give much more power so the generator "threshold" is reached even sooner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes a (IC2) generator will trigger a new piece of coal to burn when it's internal buffer is no longer full, but that means it will burn a full piece of coal each time a machine requests some power

there are several ore processing solutions available that will take processed materials from one machine to the next, though by the time you can set up most of them you don't care about fuel as much as you'd have a renewable powerplant up and running as well

Comment: Good answer, I would only chime in with not to worry about this too much. You will jump up to other generator types that are not as wasteful pretty quickly.